# How ca I make CentOS 7 accept SSH while denying SCP?

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp

On a [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7 server, I'd like to configure it such that:

1. It *accepts* SSH connections, like [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY)
2. It *denies* SCP/SFTP connections, like [SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy), [WinSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP), and [FileZilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla)

Is such a configuration possible?

Comment: See possible solutions and other detail on the topic here: https://serverfault.com/questions/28858/is-it-possible-to-prevent-scp-while-still-allowing-ssh-access

Comment: It does not make sense. If you allow a shell access, the user can do anything with the system. Disabling scp/sftp does not prevent the user from uploading/downloading files/data. It just makes it less convenient.

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You have indicated that you have a security problem (which you have not expressed) and you have asked for what you believe is the solution to this problem.  Instead, perhaps ask a new Question where you state the security problem and obtain Answers that don't assume the solution you write about here as the starting point...

Comment: If you give people shell access, they're going to be able to **create files** directly, as in simply `echo my stuff>> newfile.sh`.

Answer (score 35):

It wouldn't help you because the user could trivially do:

```
ssh user@host "cat /path/to/file" > /local/path/to/file
cat /local/path/to/file | ssh user@host "cat - > /path/to/file"
```

to copy files down and up respectively.

Comment: I mean, there’s even [a ready-made protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_transferred_over_shell_protocol) for it.

Comment: Well, it is not to difficult to transfer files in this way...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

To disable sftp, find the line that starts with `Subsystem sftp` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file (by default, it's near the very end of the file). Comment it out (put a `#` at the beginning of the line) and restart sshd.

SCP has no such configuration, the client `scp` program simply expects the remote `scp` executable to be in the user's path. So, just delete the `scp` binary to disable it. (And then you have to remember to delete it again every time you update your SSH package.)

But, as other people have said, this is not going to stop the users from uploading and downloading files. It just makes it ever-so-slightly more difficult. So, if you're doing this for security reasons, you really need to reconsider.

Comment: Note also that as of OpenSSH 8.7, the `scp` program can actually use the SFTP protocol internally (and it's going to become the default mode of operation later). You thus have to disable both protocols to actually stop people from using `scp`. (It's still pointless when shell access is available.)

Comment: Yes, this is originally for security. Since this seems not practical, we need to find some other solution. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @OliverChen: I used to triansfer files in/out with uuencode and copy/paste because it was more convenient than the lousy FTP client I had at the time. You can't win.